# How to remove moisture from kitchen air?

Tags: kitchens, air-quality, hood

Our new home has a kitchen in a corner without a vent-out channel.

As far as I understand, standard kitchen hoods can't condensate and collect water from the air they process.

What can be an alternative to dry the air during cooking?

Comment: Can always crack an outside door or window a few inches

Comment: In this case depending on the weather I have no certainty how much moisture has the chance to suck into the ceiling.

Comment: What is the age of the home? If built in the last 30 years the exhaust vent would be required to vent outside the structure. If you have a range hood it should vent to the exterior of the building, more information on why you think a "vent channel" is not there or how the corner kitchen is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [**small kitchen dehumidifier**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000H0ZDD2)?

[image]